# Don't see any scripts in Firebug "Script" menu

Tags: firebug

I have enabled Firebug for scipts for my site.

But I do not see any in the Script dropdwon menu.

The Net tab has them listed as ok.

I tried another web site not mine same thing?

Answer (score 11):

Same as @SebastianZartner said:

### Since Firefox 50 the Script panel does not work anymore!

> **Firebug** won't work anymore once [multi-process Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Multiprocess_Firefox) is enabled and
>   features like the Script panel are already starting to break.

So it seems we invited to:

### Firefox `DevTools` in [Firefox Developer Edition](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/developer/)

*It provide a Firebug theme to make the transition not too hard*

[image]

---

**It look likes nice but `Firefox` team should work on it hard!**

When i compare `Google Chrome Web Inspector` And `Firefox DevTools` in Firefox developer edition, `Chrome Web Inspector` wins! But i love Firefox, and i update it to find it as a superpower debugger in its next versions.

Answer (score 8):

I was having trouble with Firebug the last couple days while doing some javascript development as well.  Most of the time the javascript files are available on the scripts tab, but sometimes they are not (even though they are listed on other tabs).  I have found that if I disable and then re-enable the script tab followed by refreshing the page then the scripts start to show up again.

Hope you find this helpful.

Comment: Hi Jeremy.  I don't know if this helped the OP, but it sure helped me.  Thanks!  Helpful to not have to restart mozilla.

Comment: I could see the js files in the net tab, but nothing was showing up in the script tag. Thanks so much, disabling, enabling, and then refreshing the page solved it for me as well.

Answer (score 4):

The answer for this is [given in the Firebug FAQ](http://getfirebug.com/faq#Why_does_the_Script_panel_claim_there.27s_no_JavaScript_on_the_page_when_there_obviously_is_code).
In older Firefox versions this is generally due to a syntax error in your script. So, you should check your [*Console* panel](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console_Panel) for errors related to your code.

Though note that since Firefox 50 the *Script* panel does not work anymore. I.e. it always shows that message even when the scripts do not have any syntax errors. This is obviously due to a change in the Firefox code. And because [Firebug is not maintained anymore](http://getfirebug.com/), this bug won't get fixed anymore. Therefore, Firebug users are advised to switch to the [Firefox DevTools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools).

Answer (score 2):

None of these solutions helped me.  But I found another solution.  In the Net tab right click on the script you wish to view/debug, and click on 'Inspect in Script Tab'.  This immediately brought up the script I needed to debug in the Script tab.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and the solution was to "Clear Activation List" (firebug menu).

Comment: Thank you so much for posting this response. This totally helped me! Now I need to go understand why. It seems that when my "Script" panel is enabled, the functionality on my website doesn't work as expected. But as soon as I disable it, everything starts working like normal again. Very curious!

Answer (score 1):

[EDIT] I was wrong; external JS is referenced like this: `<script type="text/javascript" src="/content/js/master.js></script>`

The solution is: The "Script" menu only allows to enable or disable the JavaScript debugging for a site (since it can make Firefox very slow).

To see the actual script, you must use the hidden dropdown right above the "Script" menu. There are four buttons in the line above the "Script" dropdown: Firebug (just the logo), "Examine", "All" and the one where you can select the script to examine.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can see inline script - you'll just have to scroll through the html to get to where you want.

Comment: You see the inline JS by looking at the HTML code in the HTML tab. "external" means it's not part of the HTML file; it's referenced via a "link" tag. Open the HTML for this very page with Firebug and open the "head" tag and you'll find plenty of examples for external and internal JS.

Comment: I am not talking about inline script, external js file. I did open this page in Firebug and all the external scripts are referenced by a script tag not link tag. And no scripts show up in my Script dropdown menu????

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem for 2nd page under tabbed browsing.
Solution: After I closed the first tab I was able to debug scripts on the 2nd tab.

Answer (score 0):

The files are located in the drop down just above the "Script" tab. It just looks like a normal button, but when you click it, the list of files is shown.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem also. In my case, the issue was that the HTML was not correct - some content inserted from other code early in the output had an unclosed script tag.

Answer (score 0):

It old post but anyway maybe it help somebody. I have some problem with Firebug and scripts.  Script dropdwon menu don't show my script. Fist check if all path to script in  Html part code is correct. And second I find Firebug don't show script with error. If your can see scrip in firebug and after don't can.  This mean error in scrip.

Answer (score 0):

I am disperate that Javascript panel not work for new version Firefox!
So, if you want to work using Firebug. Use Firefox 49!