# Why isn't Firebug stepping into my script when I say "Step In"?

Tags: javascript, html, firebug

I'm trying to generate a page where the basic data to be shown can be interpreted different ways.  So I've got a data format, and a few different JS scripts to generate HTML from the data.  Each script contains a function called `BuildView` that inputs the data, parses it, and uses `document.write` to output HTML.  The server-side scripts insert the right data and a script-include for the appropriate view into the page.  Pretty straightforward, right?

Except nothing's showing up in the page.  So I decided to try and debug it with Firebug.  Here's the basic structure of the page:

```
<!DOCTYPE blah blah blah>
<html>
<head>blah blah blah</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/view.js"></script>
<div id='main-page'>
  <h1 align="center">TITLE</h1>

  <p align="left"><strong>Data: </strong>
    <div id="data-view">
      <script type="text/javascript">
        BuildView('data from server');
      </script>
    </div>
  </p>
</div>
</body></html>
```

Nothing shows up inside the `data-view` div.  I loaded Firebug, switched to the script tab, put a breakpoint on the call to `BuildView`, and reloaded the page.  It stopped at the breakpoint, and I hit <kbd>F11</kbd> (Step Into), hoping to find myself inside the `BuildView` script to look around and see what's going on.  Instead... I got nothing.  It just stepped over it and finished rendering the page.  No errors are reported, but nothing's actually happening.

If you can't tell, I haven't used Firebug before.  What am I missing?  How do I get the script debugger to actually debug into this script?

Comment: Have you tried a breakpoint inside BuildView? You should also try google chrome's debugger. Also, why use `document.write`?  Make it less obtrusive by having BuildView set the innerHTML of `"#data-view"`, then you can dynamically change the contents...

Comment: I suggest trying a simpler, static test page with the javascript, then when that's working have the server include it dynamically.  If the static page doesn't work, share it with us in a jsfiddle.

Comment: @Juan: I can't put a breakpoint inside BuildView because it isn't showing up in Firebug.  It's in an external file, and for whatever reason, that's not showing up in the script tab.

Comment: @MasonWheeler Did you try my suggestions in my answer? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/797159/dont-see-any-scripts-in-firebug-script-menu also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure the script is actually loading.
2. Put a `console.log()` or `alert()` in the function to make sure it is actually firing.
3. The `<script></script>` tag in the div, move to the end of the `</body>` tag.
4. Try running `BuildView()` from the console to see if it works after the page has loaded.

Let me know how those go.

Comment: Using `alert` statements helped me track down the problem.  There was a syntax error in my `BuildView` (which for some reason, nothing ever complained about to me) and once I fixed that, I got it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Google chrome's debugger](http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/scripts.html). Firebug has issues with displaying files that were loaded dynamically.

Another thing to try is to set firebug to show eval scripts also. From the button right next to the play/pause button

[image]